# sorting object item based on key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to sort the object based on 3rd key , here is my boject

```
a = [["AED",1,1],
    ["AFN",22.08086,1],
    ["ALL",27.171554,0],
    ["AMD",105.058803,1], 
    ["ANG",0.487406,0],
    ["AOA",227.493716,0],
    ["ARS",95.308373,0],
    ["AUD",0.420237,0],
    ["AWG",0.487406,0],
    ["AZN",0.462914,0],
    ["BAM",0.490727,0],
    ["BBD",0.544588,1]]
```

required output

```
a = [["AED",1,1],
    ["AFN",22.08086,1],
    ["AMD",105.058803,1],
    ["AMD",105.058803,1],
    ["ALL",27.171554,0],
    ["ANG",0.487406,0],
    ["AOA",227.493716,0],
    ["ARS",95.308373,0],
    ["AUD",0.420237,0],
    ["AWG",0.487406,0],
    ["AZN",0.462914,0],
    ["BAM",0.490727,0],
    ["BBD",0.544588,0]]
```

So based on final key that is 1 0r 0 it should be sorted

Comment: Use this function, please: 
a.sort((item1, item2) => item1[0] > item2[0])

Comment: @happysmile have you tried your suggestion? does it lead to the desired result? Most certainly not because (1) it should be sorted by *last* element of the inner array and (2) the callback of `sort` must return a *number* and not a *boolean*

Comment: @vellai, sorry, please try to use with this code. I tried it on my side and it seems correct.
code: a.sort((a, b) => a[2] > b[2] ? -1 : a[2] === b[2] ? 0 : 1)